# Delegate subdomain to Azure

Tags: azure, dns

I have a domain hosted at a Domain registrar and want to delegate a subdomain to Azure DNS, without having to migrate the parent domain. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

To delegate an Azure DNS subdomain, you must first delegate your public domain to Azure DNS. See [Delegate a domain to Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns) for instructions on how to configure your name servers for delegation. Once your domain is delegated to your Azure DNS zone, you can delegate your subdomain.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does tha mean that I have to migrate the parent domain to Azure DNS? I just want to delegate the subdomain and not the parent domain. So what I actually want to do is that mentioned hier for AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html